# NSDateFormatter returning null when trying to fetch date from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get date from string. But it's returning null value. Can anyone tell the reason? I think date formatter is incorrect. Below is the code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-02-28 05:50:15";
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateFromString); //It's giving me null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string you specified is not correct. The month and day fields are in wrong place (That need to be interchanged).

You need to change that to:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: O my God. I didn't noticed the difference of MM-dd. It's working absolutely fine now. Thanks a lot.